# Laravel Model Relationship - Search not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, postgresql, lumen

Laravel Model Relationship - Search not working
it wil fetched more records which is not needed

1)Relation: define function in cmsUser.php (Model)

```
    public function userDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\UserDetail', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

2)code implemnt in userrepo.php

```
    $cmsUser = CmsUser::with('userDetails');

    if ($request->has('search') && $request['search']!="") {
        $searchString = trim($request['search']);
        $cmsUser->whereHas('userDetails', function ($query) use ($searchString) {
              $query->whereNotNull('emp_code')
                    ->where('first_name', 'ilike', '%' . $searchString . '%')
                    ->orWhere('last_name', 'ilike', "%" . $searchString . "%")
                    ->orWhere('email', 'ilike', "%" . $searchString . "%")
                    ->orWhere('contact_number', $searchString);
        });           
    }

    if($admin_type != 'superadmin'){
        if (isset($organisation_id) && $organisation_id != "") {
            $cmsUser->where('organisation_id', $organisation_id);
        }
    }
    
    $cmsUser->whereNull('admin_type')->orWhereIn('admin_type', ['hq','store']);
    $userList = $cmsUser->orderByDesc('updated_at')->paginate($perPage, '*', 'page', $page)->toArray();
```

Comment: Its not typo mistake, ilke is match case insensitive

Comment: what's not working?? i don't get you. you are getting more rows than expected??